# Linked lists/pointers in C

Tags: c, list, pointers

```
typedef struct A A;
typedef struct A* AList;


struct A{
    char* name;
    AList *next;
};

AList create(char *name)
{
    AList new = (AList)malloc(sizeof(AList));
    new->name = name;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

void add(char* name, AList *aList)
{
    AList list = *aList;
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        list = create(name);
        *aList = list;
    }
    else
    {
        while (list->next != NULL)
            list = list->next;
        list->next = create(name);
    }
}
```

Hello! This is the code I have troubles with. Everything works correctly, I only get "assignment from incomaptible pointer type" in the last two lines of the code, and I don't know why. If I change pointers so they have compatible types(in my opinion i.e. list = *list->next;) I get segmentation fault. How can I fix this?
Thanks for the help,
Muco

Comment: There is a reason I don't recommend making type alias that are pointers, like your `AList` type alias, because then it's easy to forget that is a pointer and by mistake make something a pointer to a pointer, like you do with the `next` structure member, or to allocate the wrong size.

Comment: Try not to hide pointers into a `typedef` aliases - Your `create` function is wrong, you allocate space for `AList`, which is a `A*`, while you should be allocating space for `struct A`.

Comment: I'm not a code purist, but doesn't this way look nicer? And more, so I should allocate the memory for A but return the A* like 
AList new = (AList)malloc(sizeof(A)); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
struct A{
    char* name;
    AList *next;
};
```

to this

```
struct A{
    char* name;
    AList next;
};
```

The function `create`'s return type is `AList`, which is defined as `A*`. But `A::next`'s type is `AList*`, which is `A**`, so you got incompatible type.